# Convergence of $\sum\left(\frac{a_{2n-1}}{1+a_{2n-1}}\right)^2$ if $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{a_{2n-1}}{1+a_{2n-1}})^2$$ where $a_n>0$ for all $n>0$, and $\sum a_n$ converges.

Let $b_n=(\frac{a_{2n-1}}{1+a_{2n-1}})^2$ then I have $$b_n=(\frac{a_{2n-1}}{1+a_{2n-1}})^2=(1-\frac{1}{1+a_{2n-1}})^2\geq1-\frac{2}{1+a_{2n-1}}$$ by Bernoulli's inequality. ($-\frac{1}{1+a_{2n-1}}\geq-1$ since $a_n>0$, so Bernoulli is applicable.)

But $b_n\geq 1-\frac{2}{1+a_{2n-1}}\to1-2=-1\not= 0$ hence $\sum b_n$ diverges.($a_n\to0$ since $\sum a_n$ converges)

Is my answer correct? accually I didn't learn Bernoulli from the class, so I'm not confident enough to use it.

EDIT: $b_n\to0$ is still possible, so I guess this is wrong. any hint?

Comment: Can't apply comparison - one is positive and the other is negative (in particular RHS sums to $-\infty$).

Comment: @Cauchy you're right, I just noticed that. then how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

$$b_n \le a_{2n-1}^2$$

Use the fact that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is absolutely convergent then so is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$. Also if a series converges then so does any subseries.

Comment: using the ratio test to prove the fact you used, right?

Comment: @user159234 no it's a classical one. You can look it up.

Comment: $a_n^2 \leq C| a_n|$ since $a_n \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum a_n$ converges absolutely (because $a_n>0$), $\sum a_{2n-1}$ also converges absolutely, so $\sum a_{2n-1}^2$ also converges. Now, consider limit of $$\dfrac{\left(\frac{a_{2n-1}}{1+a_{2n-1}}\right)^2}{a_{2n-1}^2}=\left(\frac{1}{1+a_{2n-1}}\right)^2\to 1$$
hence from limit comparison test $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{a_{2n-1}}{1+a_{2n-1}}\right)^2$ converges.